# Casting and Generics constraints

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I have this event class:

```
sealed class AnEvent : EventArgs
{
    IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<AnAbstractClass>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
class ItemsProcessor 
{
    delegate void OnItemsProcessedHandler(object sender, AnEvent e);
    event OnItemsProcessedHandler OnItemsProcessed;
    //...
}
```

I use this wrapper class:

```
sealed class ItemWrapper<T>
            where T: AnAbstractClass 
{
    T Item { get; set; }
    Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    ItemWrapper(T item, Metadata metadata) 
    {
        Item = item;
        Metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

And I have this method in `ItemsProcessor` class :

```
internal void DoSomethingWithList<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) 
            where T: AnAbstractClass, new()
{
    IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<T>> processedItems = WrapItems<T>(items);
    OnItemsProcessed(this, new AnEvent() { Items = processedItems }); //error here
}
```

The issue is on the last line of this code sample; when I try to set the property `Items` of `AnEvent` with my local `IEnumerable`. The compiler refuses to proceed telling me that it cannot implicitly cast an `IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<T>>` to an `IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<AnAbstractClass>>`. I thought it should be okay since I added the constraint `where T: AnAbstractClass, new()` for this method but even when explicitly casting (using either classic casting with parenthesis or using `Convert<>`) I get an `InvalidCastException`.

My current workaround for the method `DoSomethingWithList` is :

```
var temp = processedItems.Select(x =>
    {
        return new ItemWrapper<AnAbstractClass>(x.Item, x.Metadata);
    });
OnItemsProcessed(this, new AnEvent() { Items = temp });
```

So it is working fine now but I was wondering why couldn't it work without using this `LINQ` conversion which has to iterate over all the items in the list? It seems obvious to me that you should be able to cast it without any error since I added the constraint *and* even with an explicit cast to make the compiler accepts my code there is an exception raised... Anyone could point me what is going wrong here?

```
abstract class AnAbstractClass 
{
}

class ItemClass : AnAbstractClass
{
}
```

A `WrapItems` quick implementation for easy copy-pasting if you want to try:

```
IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<T>> WrapItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
        where T : AnAbstractClass, new()
{
    List<ItemWrapper<T>> ret = new List<ItemWrapper<T>>();

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ret.Add(new ItemWrapper<T>(item, new Metadata()));
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Your event class does not even compile. Please post working code.

Comment: Added the "I" to "Enumerable" and two classes at the end of the post, thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Your class `ItemWrapper<T> where T:AnAbstractClas`s have no inheritance connection with `AnAbstractClass`. Compiler knows nothing about their connection.

Comment: Even if you add explicit cast operator to definition of your `ItemWrapper<T>`, generic [covariance/contravariance]c(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) works only with inheritance, not user casts. Your `ItemWrapper` must be inherited from AnAbstractClass.

Comment: @nsinreal thank you for your insights; I don't want the `ItemWrapper` to inherit the abstract class though. What I don't understand is why I can't cast a `IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<T>>` to a `IEnumerable<ItemWrapper<AnAbstractClass>>` when I explicitly add the constraint saying that `T` inherits from `AnAbstractClass`

Comment: Your class `ItemWrapper<T> where T:AnAbstractClass` have no inheritance connection with `AnAbstractClass`. Compiler knows nothing about their connection. You haven't defined implicit/explicit cast operators, so you can't even cast manually `ItemWrapper<ABC>` to `ABC`

Comment: @nsinreal I am really confused I actually did not write correctly the event class in my post... I corrected it, look at the `Items` property. Really sorry again!

Comment: When you are using `AnAbstractClass` as a generic type constriaint, it doesn't seem very generic. Why not just type you parameters as `AnAbstractClass` and avoid all the generic complications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `ItemWrapper` to

```
sealed class ItemWrapper
{
    AnAbstractClass Item { get; set; }
    Metadata Metadata { get; set; }

    ItemWrapper(AnAbstractClass item, Metadata metadata) 
    {
        Item = item;
        Metadata = metadata;
    }
}
```

what have you lost?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I need it to be generic because I am using an external library which has these similar generic constraints everywhere. However I managed to change a few things in it and it works like a charm now.